# Find optimal weights for multivariate model for classification using Machine learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization, pytorch, ranking

I am wondering if there are any suggestions on the best approach to find the optimal weights for a classification problem involving multiple variable inputs. I'm currently unclear on the approach for how to do this using neural nets or multivariate nonlinear regression in tensorflow or pytorch. The formula I'm trying to optimize is below to find the best [w0, w1] for my data [x0, x1, x2, x3].

```
y = (1 + w0 * x0 + w1 * x1) / (1 + w0 * x2 + w1 * x3)
```

I am not clear on the approach and suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimize for multiple variables in `pytorch`, you can create a `tensor` of the length of the number of variables that you have. Make sure that your `tensor` has `autograd` enabled by setting `requires_grad = True`, neural nets in Pytorch have this set to `True` by default but regular tensors have it set to `False` by default. Then create your loss function using indexes of your tensor as the variables,  and use gradient descent like you would for a normal neural net. Here's an example for you:

```py
import torch
from torch.optim import SGD

# Initialize weights.
w = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True)
optimizer = SGD([w], lr=0.01)

# Let's assume we have some data.
# These should be replaced with your actual data.
x0, x1, x2, x3 = torch.randn(4)
y_target = torch.randn(1)

for i in range(1000):  # Number of optimization steps.
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    # Compute y according to the given formula.
    y = (1 + w[0] * x0 + w[1] * x1) / (1 + w[0] * x2 + w[1] * x3)

    # Make y the same shape as y_target
    # (there will be a warning otherwise because y is a scalar)
    y = y.unsqueeze(0)
    
    # Compute the loss. Here we use mean squared error (MSE) loss.
    loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(y, y_target)
    
    # Backpropagation.
    loss.backward()
    
    # Update the weights.
    optimizer.step()

    if i % 100 == 0:  # Print loss every 100 steps.
        print(f'Iteration {i}, Loss {loss.item()}')
        
print(f'Optimized weights: {w.data}')
```