# Are there any root finding algorithms that are differentiable? Specifically in `autograd`?

Tags: machine-learning, autograd, automatic-differentiation

I am new to the world of differentiable programming / machine learning etc. I am trying to write a program that solves a nonlinear equation. I want this program to be differentiable so that I can then optimise the parameters of the equation with respect to a desired outcome. I am using [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd). My first thought is to use a root finding algorithm to solve the nonlinear equation. But I can't seem to find such a tool within `autograd`. Does anything exist? And if not, could someone point me in the right direction towards writing my own implementation?

Comment: I wrote an answer recently to a similar question.  This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76221337/find-optimal-weights-for-multivariate-model-for-classification-using-machine-lea/76221922#76221922